# Pebble Data Logging for Android not doing anything

Tags: android, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I'm new to using pebble and I downloaded their ocean survey demo program found here: https://github.com/pebble/pebble-sdk-examples/tree/master/data-logging-demo/OceanSurveyDemo-Android

But when I run it and the demo on cloudpebble, all I see is a black screen on my android app. I was wondering if there is anything else I'm missing to get data logging to work properly here? I also attempted a few of their other examples as shown here: http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/mobile-apps/android/android-datalogging/

And I get DATA_LOGGING_SUCCESS returned from the logging session on cloudpebble but again, nothing shows up on my phone when I use their provided receiving code:

```
package com.getpebble.dataloggingtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.getpebble.android.kit.PebbleKit;
import com.getpebble.android.kit.PebbleKit.PebbleDataLogReceiver;

import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * MainActivity class
 * Implements a PebbleDataLogReceiver to process received log data, 
 * as well as a finished session.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  // Configuration
  private static final UUID WATCHAPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("12258306-6cff-4b67-8af3-6f14105e8d8f");
  private static final int DATA_LOG_TAG_COMPASS = 52;

  // App elements
  private PebbleDataLogReceiver dataloggingReceiver;
  private TextView textView;
  private StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Setup TextView
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setText("Waiting for logging data...");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Define data reception behavior
    PebbleDataLogReceiver dataloggingReceiver = new PebbleDataLogReceiver(WATCHAPP_UUID) {

      @Override
      public void receiveData(Context context, UUID logUuid, Long timestamp, Long tag, int data) {
        // Check this is the compass headings log
        if(tag.intValue() == DATA_LOG_TAG_COMPASS) {
          // Get the compass value and append to result StringBuilder
          resultBuilder.append("Heading: " + data + " degrees");
          resultBuilder.append("\n");
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFinishSession(Context context, UUID logUuid, Long timestamp, Long tag) {
        super.onFinishSession(context, logUuid, timestamp, tag);

        // Display all compass headings received
        textView.setText("Session finished!\n" + "Results were: \n\n" + resultBuilder.toString());
      }

    };

    // Register DataLogging Receiver
    PebbleKit.registerDataLogReceiver(this, dataloggingReceiver);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Always unregister callbacks
    if(dataloggingReceiver != null) {
      unregisterReceiver(dataloggingReceiver);
    }
  }
}
```

I must be misunderstanding something, but why is my phone not getting any data? I don't see any errors in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not getting any data because you need to push buttons on the watch to start the sending of data to the watch.

Comment: Hmm i can try again tonight and check, i thought i was pressing the correct buttons on the simulator but perhaps not (i can do this off of the simulator on cloudpebble, correct? As my physical watch has not yet arrived for testing)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do it in the emulator just fine!

Comment: Hmm no it definetely isn't sending anything. Do I have to pair it with the pebble time app first or something? Because I can't get it to do that either